# Read file and send across a socket connection not looping

Tags: c, sockets, loops, logic

I am trying to open a file, read it in, and then send it line by line across a socket connection to a waiting client. The issue i'm getting is for some reason the loop isn't working, it will only send the first line of the file each time I touch off the "LIST" command.

```
                   else if (cmd.compare(list) ==0) /* LIST user input */
                    {
                        file_ptr = fopen("file1.txt", "r");

                        while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file_ptr) != NULL) {

                                    {

                                    while(!feof(file_ptr))
                                    send (new_s, buf, strlen(buf) + 1, 0);
                                    printf("%s",buf);
                                }


                    }

                            fclose(file_ptr);
                    }
```

Can anyone see what i'm doing wrong?

**Output from the "LIST" command on the client side (LIST was typed each time in order to get these results)**

LIST

ECHO:matthew funk    3123214321

LIST

ECHO:3123214321

LIST

ECHO:tthew funk    3123214321

LIST

ECHO:23214321

LIST

ECHO:hew funk    3123214321

LIST

ECHO:214321

LIST

ECHO:w funk    3123214321

LIST

ECHO:4321

LIST

ECHO:funk    3123214321

^C

**Contents of the file being read in**

"file1.txt" 12L, 399Cc

matthew funk    3123214321

1000Jonny   Applesee7655431234

1001Billy   Joel    7312431234

1002Billy   Idol    123456789

1003Jean    Doe     9876543211

1000 peauntbuJelly   123456789

1001 mother  THreasea987654321

1000 peter   paul    and

1000 COmputernetworki12341234123

1001 COmputernetworki12341234123

1002 COmputernetworki12341234123

1003 COmputernetworki12341234123

Comment: What is the `while(!feof(file_ptr))` supposed to do (besides create an infinite loop). I don't think that's your real code, since there would be no way out of that loop.

Comment: @user

I thought that would send the output of the file line by line until it  hits the EOF

Comment: The `while(fgets...` loop *will* send the file line by line until it hits the EOF. The `while(!feof...)` loop does nothing useful. You probably should have an inner loop that keeps calling `send` until all the bytes have been sent, but the `while(!feof...)` is definitely not the way to do that.

Comment: Ok, I made the change to the while(!feof

I still need to type "LIST" to get it to send the line each time, instead of looping and sending all lines of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file_ptr) != NULL) {
{
    while(!feof(file_ptr))
        send (new_s, buf, strlen(buf) + 1, 0);
    printf("%s",buf);
}
```

The `while (!feof(file_ptr))` loop is pointless. You're sending the same thing over and over again until `feof()` occurs, which it never will because you aren't reading from the file. And you already have a test for EOF in the form of the prior `!= NULL`.

I wouldn't use `fgets()` for this, or `strlen()` either. There's no need to make assumptions about the data. In this case you're assuming it's text with no embedded nulls. All you need is this:

```
size_t count;
while ((count = fread(buf, 1, sizeof buf, file_ptr)) > 0)
{
    send(new_s, buf, count, 0);
}
```

As a matter of fact I wouldn't use `stdio` for this either, just `open()`, `read()`, and `close()` ...

Comment: That works awesome! Thank you!

So that I understand it for future uses though, can you walk through what the "while" loop is doing?

For example the number 1 after buf, and why is it being compared to greater than 0?

ALso how is count working with no incrimination on it?

In the send command what is the 0 there doing? According to the documentation on "send' thats the place holder for flags.. does zero mean there are no flags?